# Alert + Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, alert

I have an angled application where I am trying to perform an insert methods on a backend. I need that after the response of the backend display an alert like for example the one of SweetAlert. But I do not know any components that do this. SweetAlert works at the click of a button, not the response of a backend.

For exemple:
[image]

My real question is:

How do I enable SweetAlert in typescript

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please see [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3001761)

Comment: SweetAlert would work wherever you call it

Comment: can you let us know, what have you tried so far? where is the problem you see in your code?

Comment: @charlietfl But how do I call it in typescript after the call of a Subscrible? Could you leave a response with a similar code? I tried everything but I could not

Comment: Same way it would get invoked in an event listener

Comment: You could leave a response with the code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a http request and subscribe it in you desired component and on success of http request, as you get response-  show alert.

### service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

        export class CcDataServiceService {
     constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  <-- httpclient for angular6
      }

          getData(): Observable<any[]> {
            return this.http.get('https://')
              .map(this.extractData)
              .catch(this.handleError);
          }


          private extractData(res: Response) {
            const body = res.json();
            return body || [];
          }

          private handleError(error: any) {
            const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
              error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
            console.error(errMsg);
            console.log('Server Error!');
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
          }
        }
```

### component.ts

```
import swal from 'sweetalert'
    constructor(public jsonDataService: CcDataServiceService) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        let thisx = this;

            this.jsonDataService.getData().subscribe(
              function (success) {
                // alert here on success
                 swal("Hello world!");
              },
              error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + 
             JSON.stringify(error)));


    }
```

Link:-  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-7scyt7?file=app/app.component.ts